# calculate value based on 2 fields in SQL database

Tags: sql

I can do this with linq easy but i got a situation where i have to create a stored procedure to return true or false based on 2 fields(minrange,maxrange) in  table B. So, the goal is given an id from table A, i select the range value from table A and compare this value to the 2 ranges in table B. If the value is within range(minrange,maxrange) return true. Thanks.

Comment: is there some way to join to tableB?

Comment: Can you share your tables definition?

Comment: Is there a foreign key relationship between the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing specifics (as to foreign keys), this syntax should work.

```
SELECT 
    CAST((CASE
            WHEN tableAValue < tableB.maxRange and tableAValue > tableB.minRange 
              THEN 1
            ELSE 
              0 
          END) AS BIT) 
FROM TableA
  INNER JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.ID = TableB.TableAID
WHERE TableA.ID = @yourID
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a field that allows you to join records from Table A to Table B.  I'll call it "CategoryID".  Try this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN TableA.Value BETWEEN TableB.MinValue AND TableB.MaxValue 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM TableA 
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.CategoryID = TableB.CategoryID
WHERE TableA.ID = "TheID"
```

Good luck!

-Michael

Comment: This returns an integer value rather than a bit (true/false)

Comment: Correct.  I chose to leave the cast off for simplicity, because I think it was the CASE statement that was really at issue in the question.  The use of a bit to represent true or false is actually somewhat arbitrary (though I, for one, always do it) and didn't want to confuse the answer with what might be an unnecessary cast.